# How to connect two applications in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got simple login application in spring boot with this main class:

```
package com.pai;

import com.pai.dao.userDao;
import com.pai.entity.User;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjektpaiApplication {

    @ Autowired
    private userDao dao;

    @ Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        SpringApplication . run ( ProjektpaiApplication . class , args ) ;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init ()
    {
        dao.save(new User("admin", "admin", "admin", passwordEncoder.encode("passwd")));
    }
}
```

I want to connect that login app with CRUD app from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcP5kFPq354
where the main class looks like this:

```
package com.pai;

import com.pai.domain.Post;
import com.pai.domain.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjektpaiApplication2 implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private PostRepository repository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProjektpaiApplication2.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        repository.save(new Post("My post number #" + (i+1)));
    }
}
}
```

How can I connect them to create one bigger application, where I can do both, login and then use CRUD functions? I tried to put them together in one file, but it doesn't work, and when I put them in 2 separated files it's also not working

Comment: Define "connect."

Comment: I want them to work as one bigger application, where I can login and then use CRUD functions

Comment: Did you format your code like this on purpose? It's impossible to read

Comment: This is not a good question, as there is no single answer. You typically wouldn't combine two applications like these, but would run one as a web service (The login app) that the other (The CRUD app) calls. This is called SOA (Service oriented architecture).

Comment: Ok then, but still, how can I do that? Since i'm really newbie in this, is there any simple way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import App2 project in your App1 project. (It's fairly simple if you are using Eclipse)
2. Make a rest call from App1 to App2 and perform desired operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different ports, for this add the property `server.port` in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8080 # Default
server.port=0    # Random
```